# Loading languages in Dll resources

Tags: c++, windows, resources, libraries, wtl

Good day, i have a problem when changing language in application. Now i have library which consist some languages, a use WTL::CAppModule for working with recourses i write next code for loading dll:

```
void Application::LoadResources()
{
    m_resModule = ::LoadLibraryEx(_T("Res.dll"), 0, 0);
    ATLASSERT(m_resModule);
    if (!m_resModule)
    {
        ATLTRACE(_T("Resources loading failed!\n"));
        return;
    }
    m_theModule.SetResourceInstance(*m_resModule);
}
```

and function to change language for application contains next code:

```
if(prim_lang)
    {
        if(Tools::SystemTools::IsVistaOrLater())
            SetThreadUILanguage(MAKELANGID(prim_lang, sub_lang));
        else
            SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(prim_lang, sub_lang), SORT_DEFAULT));
    }
```

all worked properly but on windows xp language dosen't change in general. Maybe i wrongly use the function SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(prim_lang, sub_lang), SORT_DEFAULT));? How must i build multi-language app, may be needed separate languages to different libraries rather than save all languages in one, and load it according users choose?

Comment: I solved this problem all work perfectly sub_lan and prim_lan must pass to function SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(prim_lang, sub_lang), SORT_DEFAULT)); according you specify in rc files, all work in once library.